# Creating Outlook mail with Swedish characters from UTF-8-encoded webpage

Tags: php, internet-explorer, email, character-encoding, outlook-2007

I've got a database-driven website, written in php, which needs to create e-mails from the data. All data and every page is encoded in UTF-8, and contains plenty of the Swedish characters åäö. I've got the following in my mailto-link:

```
<a href="mailto:name@domain.com?body=Hej!%0D%0AåäöÅÄÖ">Mailto-link</a>
```

and the e-mail body is supposed to come out as

```
Hej!
åäöÅÄÖ
```

This works using Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox at least (haven't tested in Chrome or Safari) with Outlook 2007. However, in Internet Explorer 7 or earlier the åäö comes out as weird characters. Many of our clients are stuck with IE 6 and 7. Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Does the link display correctly in IE6/7, or do they show the same "bad" characters as are being displayed when Outlook opens the new message?

Comment: @jesse: The link displays correctly in IE7, so the error shows up between the browser and Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the wast number of possible browser/email client combinations out there is going to give you an endless amount of grief if you try to solve it with a "mailto:" link. Theoretically url-encoding should work, but when I've dabbled with this in the past I figured out it was easier to just send email from PHP in stead.

That brings other challenges though, such as making sure you don't make it possible for spammers to use your server as an email gateway (eg. use contact ID numbers in stead of email addresses in the form). Captcha and rate limiting is probably a good idea as well.

Comment: I think you might well have the truth of it all, therefore I'm marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you ever face a problem like this just put the content that is causing the trouble in this Javascript alert statement and paste it in address bar of a decent browser such as Opera or Firefox.

```
javascript:alert(escape("problem-string-here"));
```

For example, if you execute

```
javascript:alert(escape("åäöÅÄÖ"));
```

you will get `%E5%E4%F6%C5%C4%D6`. You can copy the text displayed by the alert statement and then use it in your mailto link:

mailto:name@domain.tld?body=Hey!%0a%E5%E4%F6%C5%C4%D6

Comment: By golly, I almost got happy there for a while! Using this, it works from IE7 to Outlook Express 6. But, then it goes haywire for IE8 and Outlook 2007 - the special characters are completely dropped. +1 for at least giving me a solution for when I know the user's computer configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent%20encoding) the characters as well (not just the line breaks) *might* help. In PHP, the right function would be [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode).

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help, and additionally it made every ' ' (space) turn into '+'-characters, even in the e-mail.

Comment: @Lizzan  ah, too bad! In that case, I don't know a solution. It's always the same mail client?

Comment: @Pekka I'm not sure, but it's probably always Outlook in one disguise or another. Thanks for trying, though! =)

Comment: @Lizzan yeah. It might be of interest to see whether it works with ISO-8859-1, which is the default encoding for E-Mails.

Comment: @Pekka Yeah, I've already tried that, and it works, but then the data which is displayed on the same page gets wonky. Is there a way to specify a different encoding for just part of a page?

Comment: @Lizzan no - you would have to either switch the whole page, or put the link into an `<iframe>` that is ISO-8859-1 encoded. It's terribly kludgy, but the only way I can think of

Comment: @Pekka I guessed as much. Thanks for helping out!