# ÅÄÖ gets out wrong in sending from a form

Tags: php, character-encoding

Im trying to get my mails from a form right with Swedish ÅÄÖåäö but it comes out wrong in mails. Anyone?
The server is set to UTF8
My header is:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'); ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>xxxxxx</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<table align="center" border="0">
<tr><td>
</html>
```

My mail.inc.php is coded like this:

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
function mail_file($to, $from, $subject, $body, $file) {
$boundary = md5(rand());
$headers = array(
    'MIME-Version: 1.0',
    //"Content-Type: multipart/mixed; charset=iso-8859-1; boundary=\"{$boundary}\"", - 170707
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{$boundary}\"",
    "From: {$from}"
);
$message = array(
    "--{$boundary}",
    'Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=iso-8859-1',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable', 
    '', 
    quoted_printable_encode($body),         '',                            
    "--{$boundary}",
    "Content-Type: {$file['type']}; name=\"{$file['name']}\"",
    "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file['name']}\"",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64", 
    '',
    chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']))),
    "--{$boundary}--",
    '',
);
mail($to, $subject, implode("\r\n", $message), implode("\r\n", $headers));
}
?>
```

This drives me nuts. Please help

Comment: All I see in your code is `charset=iso-8859-1` several times...

Comment: I deleted one of them. It comes out great now in gmail but not in hotmail :(

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if its best way to archive
Try this before your mail() function `$subject` like that

`$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';`

and then send mail

`mail($to, $subject, implode("\r\n", $message), implode("\r\n", $headers));`

OR

`mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', implode("\r\n", $message), implode("\r\n", $headers));`

Comment: Sorry but no, that did not cot it

Comment: Okay Please now refer this answer [LINK 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791869/creating-outlook-mail-with-swedish-characters-from-utf-8-encoded-webpage) and [LINK 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806154/php-mail-special-characters-in-subject-field)
Hope Here you will find solutions. :)

Comment: Nope, did not help

Comment: Sorry i never used this type mail,but i see some stuf so i said
Please try this coz its  UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding that can represent any Unicode character. ISO 8859-1 is a single-byte encoding

`$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";`